# CodeIgniter temporarily close db_debug

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

l have a problem that l need to close be_debug at the only one of the request.

on this, l want to catch the db_error myself and then to do something.

for example:

```
// now 'db_debug' option is true in database.php
$this->db->trans_begin(true);
$this->db->query('select * from `not_exist_table`');
$st = $this->db->trans_status();
if($st === false){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a public property so you can set the value directly

```
$this->db->db_debug = false;
```

The change is not written to the config file.